# Comparing SKColor of two nodes for both OSX and iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, sprite-kit, nscolorspace

I'm working on [a subclass of `SKLabelNode` allowing line-breaks](https://github.com/nickfalk/NORLabelNode) through the use of the new-line character `\n`. It is coming along nicely and I am currently in the process of making sure it works for OSX as well as iOS before preparing a podspec.

On the surface it seems to be working, but one of my tests is failing when building for OSX, despite passing for iOS. It is somehow `NSColorSpace` related but this is uncharted territory for me. This is the method in the class that copies the color to the subnodes:

```
- (void)setFontColor:(SKColor *)fontColor{
    [super setFontColor: fontColor];
    self.propertyStateholderNode.fontColor    = fontColor;
    for (SKLabelNode *subNode in self.subNodes) {
        subNode.fontColor    = fontColor;
    }
    _fontColor    = fontColor;
}
```

and this is the test that is failing, (I've removed tests towards other properties which passes on both platforms):

```
- (void)testThatSubnodesInheritsPropertiesFromParent{
    NORLabelNode *threeLineNode    = [self nodeWithThreeSubNodes];
    threeLineNode.fontColor    = [SKColor greenColor];

    for (SKLabelNode *subNode in threeLineNode.subNodes) {
        XCTAssertEqualObjects(threeLineNode.fontColor, subNode.fontColor, @"The subnodes should have the same fontColor as the parent.");
    }
}
```

Details for the test failing are as follows:
((threeLineNode.fontColor) equal to (subNode.fontColor)) failed: **("NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1") is not equal to ("NSDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0.976895 0 1")** ...

It is not clear to me at all how the nodes wind up with different colorspaces...

Comment: Are you using any colors that are not presets? (Presets are: `greenColor`, `yellowColor`, etc)

Comment: Not in the test which is where I have the problem. As you can see it's a strict ´[SKColor greenColor];` nothing fancy.

Comment: Are you storing any colors or `SKNode`s on disk and then reading it cross-platform? Are either node not yet drawn to screen? (I wonder if it is Calibrated and then changed to Device when drawn, or anything like that).

Comment: Nope, there is really no to complexity to speak of. What you see above is basically it. I have no idea why the subnodes wind up with a different colorSpace and some weird floatValue lower than 1 for the green-value when I clearly specify greenColor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know that the color spaces are different I would try converting them to the same color space before comparing using [`-colorUsingColorSpace:(NSColorSpace *)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColor/colorUsingColorSpace%3a). You can resolve them to one known colorspace or convert them to each other’s color spaces. Again only on Mac is this happening and is `NSColorSpace` available.

A [post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/192301-comparing-nscolor-instances.html) on the CocoaBuilder mailing list talks about comparing the component values, but that is not ideal because the components do not distinguish rgb versus grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Sprite Kit Function Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) `SKColor` is

> A macro that expands to a platform-specific color class.
>
> ```
> #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
> #define SKColor UIColor
> #else
> #define SKColor NSColor
> #endif
> ```

As we see in [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithWhite%3aalpha%3a) and [NSColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSColor) there are different color space convenience methods.

For example if you use `colorWithWhite:alpha:` you will get a color “in the device gray colorspace” and if you use `colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` you will get a color "in the device RGB colorspace”.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts so far. :-) I'm aware that SKColor is a macro for UIColor and NSColor respectively. As you can see though I'm simply setting the property `fontColor` for both the parentNode and child-nodes to the same prepared instance of SKColor.